# How to Create Subarray Efficiently in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In my VBA program, I have a big array of data, where I need to constantly use its sub-arrays.

My method is:

```
Redim subArr(rowBegin to rowEnd)
For r = rowBegin to rowEnd
    subArr(r) = bigArr(r)
Next r
```

Is there any more efficient way to reference this kind of sub-arrays please? Thanks...

Comment: I only extract the most relevant part of my codes here. Other codes are actually not helpful for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with arrays is incredibly fast so this will probably give no discernable benefit - althouh I can understand how it may appeal from a coding sense than looping to fill a smaller array

Given you are working with a single element array you could:

1. Introduce a "marker" string inside the large array
2. `Join` the large array with a delimiter into a single string
3. `Split` the large array by the "marker" string, then separate the reduced string into a smaller array with the delimiter

The code below dumps the numbers 1 to 100 into an array, and then splits it as above to pull out the first 10 records

```
Sub test()
Dim bigArr
Dim subArr
Dim strSep As String
Dim strDelim As String
Dim strNew As String
Dim rowBegin As Long
Dim rowEnd As Long

strDelim = ","
strSep = "||"
'fill array with 1 to 100
bigArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("row(1:100)"))

rowBegin = 1
rowEnd = 10

bigArr(rowEnd + 1) = strSep
'make a single string
strNew = Join(bigArr, strDelim)
'split the string at the marker 
vArr = Split(strNew, strSep)
ReDim subArr(rowBegin To rowEnd)
'split the smaller string with the desired records
subArr = Split(Left$(vArr(0), Len(vArr(0)) - 1), strDelim)

End Sub
```

Comment: Big thanks Brettdj! This is the most brilliant way I've seen to manipulate arrays! It inspires me for other array operation as well.

Comment: BTW, do you know how the assign operator for variant actually works in VBA please? Because in this way, although the manually loop in array decreases, there is a chance that there are more loops within the assign operator as well as the split/join functions. Any ideas?

Comment: This was my first thought too. But it only works with string arrays, other types would need to be cast to string first.  And it is much slower than looping the array

Comment: What did you mean by *"do you know how the assign operator for variant actually works in VBA please"?* .On my testing the approach above took 0.09 seconds to extract 50k records from a larger array verus 0.02 seconds for the loop.

Comment: this is what i'm afraid of. although it's clean to code, but the speed is not improved.

Comment: in this method, since you change the value of the bigArr in two indexes, so i guess if i'm gonna use it, i'll have to create a temp variable tmpArr to store the bigArr and then change the content of tmpArr. in doing that, instead of looping a subarray, the program uses the "=" operator (i.e. assign operator) each time i want to create a sub array. so it's crucial how the "=" operator works in vba. for example, if "=" actually loops every item in the bigArr, then the speed would be reduced.

Comment: @stanfish while it feels cleaner (coding wise) I presume that `Join` is running its own internal loop. I had thought the code above would break even or thereabouts with the variant loop re-write, rather then 4-5 times slower.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: probably not

Not quite so short answer: since you are creating a sub array with non 0/1 bounds, why not just pass a reference to the original array and the bounds?

BTW: a good resource for VBA array's is CPearson's site http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I need to do it in this dirty way then. Actually, one of the reasons I cannot use reference and bounds is because I need to use these subarrays for regressions, and unfortunately the regression does require two "clean" arrays without empty items