# How to extract a part of array by referring start and end index just like what we do in Matlab

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

For example, if we have an array A. 
In matlab, we just use A[a:b] to get a sub array easily,where a,b are start point and end point respectively.
Is there similar way to do it in VBA?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get elements a through b? Or the string of text in the array between the a and b characters?

Comment: I am referring to the elements in an array. For example, A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. How can I get the sub array  [4,5,6] ?

Comment: [See this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167495/how-to-create-subarray-efficiently-in-vba) The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10168019/2200824) there should provide what you need...

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with arrays is incredibly fast so this will probably give no discernable benefit - although I can understand how it may appeal from a coding sense than looping to fill a smaller array

Given you are working with a single element array you could:

Introduce a "marker" string inside the large array.
Join the large array with a delimiter into a single string.
Split the large array by the "marker" string, then separate the reduced string into a smaller array with the delimiter.
The code below dumps the numbers 1 to 100 into an array, and then splits it as above to pull out the first 10 records.

```
Sub test()
Dim bigArr
Dim subArr
Dim strSep As String
Dim strDelim As String
Dim strNew As String
Dim rowBegin As Long
Dim rowEnd As Long

strDelim = ","
strSep = "||"
'fill array with 1 to 100
bigArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate("row(1:100)"))

rowBegin = 1
rowEnd = 10

bigArr(rowEnd + 1) = strSep
'make a single string
strNew = Join(bigArr, strDelim)
'split the string at the marker 
vArr = Split(strNew, strSep)
ReDim subArr(rowBegin To rowEnd)
'split the smaller string with the desired records
subArr = Split(Left$(vArr(0), Len(vArr(0)) - 1), strDelim)

End Sub
```